# How to implement priority queue in C++?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am implementing a train boarding system using priority queue. I have the working code but I need to make the following changes..

The priority levels will be : High, Medium and Low. So the passenger should input his/her name and the priority level. The train can have up to 30 passengers.
In the end I will sort the passengers accordingly... Here what I have so far my problem is taking strings as arguments instead of the integers I have now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define High 1
#define Medium 2
#define Low 3
/*
* Node Declaration
*/
struct node
{
    int priority;
    int info;
    struct node *link;
};
/*
* Class Priority Queue
*/
class Priority_Queue
{
private:
    node *front;
public:
    Priority_Queue()
    {
        front = NULL;
    }
    /*
    * Insert into Priority Queue
    */
    void insert(int item, int priority)
    {
        node *tmp, *q;
        tmp = new node;
        tmp->info = item;
        tmp->priority = priority;
        if (front == NULL || priority < front->priority)
        {
            tmp->link = front;
            front = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            q = front;
            while (q->link != NULL && q->link->priority <= priority)
                q = q->link;
            tmp->link = q->link;
            q->link = tmp;
        }
    }
    /*
    * Delete from Priority Queue
    */
    void del()
    {
        node *tmp;
        if (front == NULL)
            cout << "Queue Underflow\n";
        else
        {
            tmp = front;
            cout << "Deleted item is: " << tmp->info << endl;
            front = front->link;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    /*
    * Print Priority Queue
    */
    void display()
    {
        node *ptr;
        ptr = front;
        if (front == NULL)
            cout << "Queue is empty\n";
        else
        {
            cout << "Queue is :\n";
            cout << "Priority       Item\n";
            while (ptr != NULL)
            {
                cout << ptr->priority << "                 " << ptr->info << endl;
                ptr = ptr->link;
            }
        }
    }
};
/*
* Main
*/
int main()
{
    int choice, item, priority;
    Priority_Queue pq;
    do
    {
        cout << "1.Insert\n";
        cout << "2.Delete\n";
        cout << "3.Display\n";
        cout << "4.Quit\n";
        cout << "Enter your choice : ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Input the item value to be added in the queue : ";
            cin >> item;
            cout << "Enter its priority : ";
            cin >> priority;
            pq.insert(item, priority);
            break;
        case 2:
            pq.del();
            break;
        case 3:
            pq.display();
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong choice\n";
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use [`std::priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/)?

Comment: Could you specify clearly whether you have to implement it yourself? Otherwise the solution would be to use the standard library one.

Comment: I can actually use any data structure but I thought this is the approach

Comment: And I need to have a header file and main.cpp file so I am not sure now

Comment: On a side Note: Ont combine new with free - use delete instead. You also don't need all of those <c...> headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using string values for the queue and just translate plain-text priorities to the respective integer value, think

```
int ParsePriority(string plainTextPriority)
{
    switch(plainTextPriority) {
        case "High": return 1;
        case "Medium": return 2;
        case "Low": return 3;
    }
    throw "Unknown priority class";
}
```

You'll then be able to use the priority values like you did before.

```
case 1:
    cout << "Input the item value to be added in the queue : ";
    cin >> item;
    cout << "Enter its priority : ";
    do {
        string plainTextPriority;
        cin >> plainTextPriority;
        try {
            priority = ParsePriority(plainTextPriority)
        }
        catch {
            priority = 0;
            cout << "Could not parse the priority, please enter one of High, Medium, Low" << endl;
        }
    } while (priority == 0);
    pq.insert(item, priority);
    break;
```

I added the loop to take the case that a value that does not represent a valid priority has been entered into account.

Comment: Sorry I am asking too much. But can you add the part you wrote into my code above. I like your solution but how should I modify my code accordingly... I am confused

Comment: Never mind. I've done my best to give you the example how to use my solution in your code. I've elided everything but the first case from your switch statement. I've not tried the code, hence it's possible that there are typos, but I hope the point is clear.

Comment: Thank you so much I got what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use mapping.

```
  int main()
{
    int choice, item;
   string priority;
   map<string,int>m;
   m["High"]=1;
   m["Low"]=3;
   m["Medium"]=2;
    Priority_Queue pq;
    do
    {
        cout << "1.Insert\n";
        cout << "2.Delete\n";
        cout << "3.Display\n";
        cout << "4.Quit\n";
        cout << "Enter your choice : ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Input the item value to be added in the queue : ";
            cin >> item;
            cout << "Enter its priority : ";
            cin >> priority;
            pq.insert(item, m[priority]);//look change
    //... rest of the code will same
```

and you need to include `#include<map>` also.
Thank you.